# Cannot bind to a Property of DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

This is my first time posting a question. I'm looking into this issue for about a whole day but cannot see why this binding doesn't work.

I want a Label to display the name of a object "hotspot" which is a Property of class instance named Plan. There are multiple plans and each plan contains multiple hotspots. When I click on a hotspot the property `Plan.SelectedHotSpot` sets this clicked hotspot as value. If there is no HotSpot selected it turns to null.

XAML:

```
<Label Name="lblHotSpotName" />
```

MainWindow code behind when Plan is selected from ListBox:

```
private void lstPlans_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.Plan = PlanBLL.GetPlanByID(plans[lstPlans.SelectedIndex].ID);
    lblHotSpotName.DataContext = canvas.Plan;
    lblHotSpotName.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, "SelectedHotSpot.Name");
}
```

Plan class:

```
public class Plan : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private HotSpot selectedHotSpot;

    public HotSpot SelectedHotSpot
    {
        get { return selectedHotSpot; }

        set
        {
            selectedHotSpot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHotSpot");
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHotSpot.Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 }
```

This code doesn't seem to work when I click on a hotspot `lblHotSpotName` stays empty. 
It seems to me that when a plan is loaded SelectedHotSpot is null and so it doesn't bind to that hotspot object which is selected after the plan has been loaded.
Is my insinuation right? That this binding needs to have an existing object which is not null. And when the object changes that we need to define the binding from label to `Plan.SelectedHotSpot` again.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `HotSpot.Name` property supports `INotifyPropertyChanged`? `canvas.Plan` is not *`null`* when `lstPlans_SelectionChanged` is triggered?

Comment: HotSpot.Name is a string and doesn't change within HotSpot class so there is no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for that. The canvas.Plan is never null when lstPlans_SelectionChanged is triggered. Only when window is loaded it's null.

Comment: Please look in your Output Window in Visual Studio and tell us what errors you see there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is no error. Only lblHotSpotName's content doesn't show the name of the SelectedHotSpot. But I think I know the whole cause of this issue. As objects that variable SelectedHotSpot in Plan Class keeps changes all the time I don't think I can bind to that. It just keeps the reference to the object which is set at the point that lstPlans_SelectionChanged is triggered which is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure that I have understood your problem exactly right because your question is somewhat unclear, but can you not just data bind to the `Label.Content` property in XAML? If you want to data bind the `SelectedHotSpot.Name` property of the `Plan` item that is currently selected in the `ListBox`, then you *should* be able to do something like this:

```
<Label Name="lblHotSpotName" 
   Content="{Binding SelectedItem.SelectedHotSpot.Name, ElementName=lstPlans}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You're still better off using XAML for your `Binding`. Add a `string` property to bind to and then update that in your `lstPlans_SelectionChanged` handler instead:

```
<Label Name="lblHotSpotName" Content="{Binding SelectedItemHotSpotName}" />
```

...

```
private void lstPlans_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.Plan = PlanBLL.GetPlanByID(plans[lstPlans.SelectedIndex].ID);
    SelectedItemHotSpotName = canvas.Plan.SelectedHotSpot.Name;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that SelectedHostSpot can be null as have different objects during run time. I've tried this. But it remains on null. Why I haven't done this is XAML is because ListBox doesn't contain Plan object but ID's which I use afterwards to get the data from the database to create a Plan Object with it. I've done this for Performance reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help or not, but in `lstPlans_SelectionChanged` try this `Binding`:

```
var myBinding = new Binding();

myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedHotSpot.Name");
myBinding.Source = canvas.Plan;
lblHotSpotName.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

If `SelectedHotSpot.Name` doesn't change, when this line is not needed:

```
OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHotSpot.Name");
```

in `SelectedHotSpot` property declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Thanks for your suggestion. So when I open up the plan. SelectedHotSpot is null. When I click on a hotSpot. The binding doesn't see the change of that property and remains on null.

Comment: @Youszef: `SelectedHotSpot` is null in *`lstPlans_SelectionChanged`*? If yes, then Binding is then also null.

Comment: yes SelectedHotSpot is null at that moment of trigger. Is there any way I can solve this issue. Or should I create a public string in class Plan that gets SelectedHotSpot.Name value when selected. And bind to that public string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any issue in the given code (though, Raise property changed for .Name is not required).

I would suggest to confirm that `selectedHotSpot` always has some instance and is not null.
Try modifying your plan class and set:

```
selectedHotSpot = new HotSpot(Name="Default")
```

and you should see "Default" in your label.

Comment: Yes this one works indeed. So there is no way I can bind to a variable where it's object changes all the time?

Comment: The binding is to an instance of object. if that object is null nothing turns up at UI.